# Completely remove Grub from computer

Tags: dual-boot

I have recently tried to update my Elementary OS from luna to freya but somehow it failed so I uninstalled the OS but somehow traces of grub is still on my computer preventing me from booting into my windows 10. Now that whenever I start my computer i receieve the message: ' error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>_ '
I tried loading the windows 10 disk from a bootable usb stick and fixed the mbr in command prompt but i still end up looking at the same message. I pretty much tried everything (turning off uefi in bios, chaning boot priorities..)
somehow i just can't get rid of grub even after uninstalling the OS. 
i really need some help, maybe i messed up my partition table? or maybe there's something wrong with the bios bootloader that keeps trying to load grub?

please check this: 
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/12181307/
and this:
- http://postimg.org/image/wy7sor9rn/

I'm unsure why sda5 became vista(i installed elementary os on this partition but then uninstalled)
I've already ran bootrec /fixmbr and fixboot and both returned succesfull in cmd (windows 10 bootable disk) but the default mbr is still grub, how can i remove it.
Can someone look at my partition table and check if the bootflag is correct or wrong? How can i rejoin the sda5 with sda3(D drive)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
- load up gparted and change the boot flag to the one which says OS (sda2 in my case)
- use the Boot Repair tool 
- reboot  :D

Answer (score 1):

I have Dell Inspiron3542 having Windows 10.Following method works for me.

1.Enter in System Setup by pressing F2.

2.Select "File Browsrr Del Boot Option" &press Enter.

It will Show list of all partitions on hard Disk.

3.Select Linux Partition You want to Delete & Hit Enter

4.Now save all  Settings by pressing F10.

Now your PC  will restart and Windows  will start normally.

[image: Setup Utility]

[image: File Browsrr Del Boot Option]